# getting square emoticons instead of actual emoticons

Tags: java, unicode, emoticons

I am working a java chat application and I am adding emoticons by replacing the emoticon shortcut, like `:)` ,with  `◕‿◕` . Its not an image that I am replacing it with but simple text. Now the problem that I am facing is that sometimes I get just `Square boxes` instead of the actual thing that I want. I am making these images/texts in MS Word by converting the unicode to the actual image. I am also using various online resources to get these images/text.

Can anyone tell me how to get rid of the boxes and get the actual text.
My encoding is in `UTF-8` and my font is also set to `monospaced`.

Answer (score 0):

Your unicode-character is probably not supported by your font. Either the font implements the character as a box, or the operating system / font-renderer draws a box instead of the glyph.

Comment: I have set my font accordingly. I can now see the glyph that is actually present. But when I am storing it in the derby database, then it is again being stored as a square box and not as the actual glyph. Any suggestions as to what I should do so that the derby database also stores it as the actual glyph.

Comment: Derby stores the characters unicode bytes, not the font. If you take the bytes out of the database and render them somehow, the *font* and *fontrenderer* will determine what you will see. You could render the font as pictures and store them in the database. Or, better, provide a font that is capable of displaying all characters you want.

Comment: If I render the font as pictures and store them in the database then I wont be able to use them as I want to as I cant replace text in a string with an image as String doesn't take image. Thus I was using the above glyph that are in the form of simple text.

Comment: Ok. I finally got it working. I just set the font of my jEditorPane to the desired font and that took care of it all. The database though not showing the glyph that I want it t show, but when I display the same in my jEditorPane, it is showing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the Font used in your application just cannot show some chars. Find one which font really can and use it there.

Font has `boolean canDisplay(char c)` method which you can use.
See also [the doc about font](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html)

Comment: I have set my font accordingly. I can now see the glyph that is actually present. But when I am storing it in the 'derby database', then it is again being stored as a square box and not as the actual glyph. Any suggestions as to what I should do so that the derby database also stores it as the actual glyph.